# How can I map through a prop of a Table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, datatable

I have a Table in React and its rows arent html elements so I can map the usual way. It`s data goes through props. Here is the example:

```
<Table
data={{head:{},data:[
{
data_creare:"20.01.2020",
detalii:"React example"
}
]}}
/>
```

I want to do something like

```
[this.state.message.map((list)=> {data_creare:list.a, detalii:list.b}]
```

but it does not work. I know how to map through html elements but not with props. Please give me an example.

This is from where I got the table and you can find documentation : [NPM package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-data-table)

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-responsive-data-table';
import axios from 'axios';






 class ListaMesaje3 extends React.Component {

 componentDidMount() {
 axios.get(`http://11111111:111111/listamesaje`)
.then(res => {
  const persons = res.data;
  console.log(persons.mesaje);
  this.setState({mesajex:persons.mesaje});
  console.log(this.state.mesajex);


 
})
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      titlu: 'Lista mesaje',
      mesajex:[],
      x:[]
     
  }
}

render() {



  
  return(
  <div id="tot">
  <h3>{this.state.titlu}</h3>

 <Table style={{
opacity: 0.8,
backgroundColor: "#00113a",
color: "#ffffff",
textAlign: "center"
```

}}
tableStyle="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-borderless
table-responsive"
pages={true}
pagination={true}
onRowClick={() => {}} // if You Want Table Row Data OnClick then assign this
{row => console.log(row)}
page={true}
errormsg="Error. . ."
loadingmsg="Loading. . ."
isLoading={false}
sort={true}
title="Lista mesaje"
search={true}
size={10}
data={{
head: {
data_creare: "Data creare",
detalii: "Detalii",

```
  },
  data:[
  {
    data_creare:"",
    detalii:""
  }
 ]



 }} />



 </div>
  );
 }

 }

export default ListaMesaje3;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems you using a third party library for "Table" it isn't html element. can you share the library?
or can you share where your "Table" fot imported from

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-data-table

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a head first as table head, then you can provide table body rows as objects according to head.

```
<Table 
    data={
        {
            head:{
                data_creare:"Data Created",
                details:"Description"
            },
            data:[
                {
                    data_creare:"20.01.2020",
                    details:"React example"
                }
            ]
        }
    }/>
```

Comment: And how can I map through the table rows ? Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Can you update your code to the question? its not formatted well,

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to map through the data, table rows should be generated autometically here, can you please elaborate more??

Comment: I am getting the data from a state object this.state.mesajex that contains the data that i need to pass it to the two props and I don`t know how

Comment: Can you list your data format to the question??